# Is There an Official Google Reader App With Widget?

Tags: app-widgets, rss, google-reader

Does anyone know if there is an official app from Google for Google Reader?

I would like an official app with a widget that displays the number of unread feed items.

Good News! [Google just added widgets to the official Google Reader App](http://googlereader.blogspot.com/2011/02/updates-to-google-reader-app-for.html).

Comment: Google added widgets to the official Google Reader App: http://goo.gl/yZwXD

Comment: Please do not use URL shorteners here.

Comment: Here's the [announcement on the Google Reader blog](http://googlereader.blogspot.com/2011/02/updates-to-google-reader-app-for.html).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the Google Reader app and service are no longer available.

Comment: @AlE. That's not what "off-topic" means. [It was agreed on meta](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/1505/12442) that being out of date isn't enough reason to close a question - especially when it already has an accepted answer!

Comment: @Dan: Meh. I wasn't suggesting deletion. Only closing. Since the app is no longer available and never coming back, this question and answers are of no use to anyone. The best argument against deleting, losing reputation, won't apply here because the question and answers have been around for longer than 60 days.

Comment: @AlE. If you think there's a reason to reopen the discussion on meta, please do so. But as the community's consensus is currently clear, I won't be voting to close any of these questions.

Comment: @Dan: I've added my views to the meta question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just downloaded the **[Official Google Reader app](http://www.appbrain.com/app/google-reader/com.google.android.apps.reader)** from the market.  No widget yet.

Answer (score 8):

There is a dearth of official apps for google's own services on google's own mobile OS.

No official Google Reader App, no official widget.

That may be because they work on optimizing the mobile versions of those web-services, to obviate the need for an additional app. You've already got the browser -- why install an app for a web-service?

This [2008 article on how gReader renders in mobile webkit](http://www.downloadsquad.com/2008/10/22/android-first-look-google-reader/) might explain some of the concept.

Comment: "Why install an app for a web-service?"

I like the idea of having a widget which displays the number of unread items instead of just clicking a link to open the web site.

Comment: I use Passpack to track my online accounts? I have 60 of them in there.. imagine using a custom app/widget for each of those services.... I'm not saying that widgets have no place. It would be nice to have a  customizable widget that could scrape a page or use an arbitrary API

Comment: So based on your logic then I pose this to you: Why does Google have an Android app for Gmail & Calendar? You could just use the Android browser connecting to the web for that too? The answer is because apps provide widgets and other client side functionality that a web app does not facilitate.

Answer (score 2):

According to my market, market differs according to your country, there is no "official google reader" app.
May I suggest downloading *NewsRob*, it's in the market and there are two versions; paid and free, and even the free version features a widget to launch the application, which is simple and light, and it even has a very good feature, you can make the app **download** all of the new **articles** or so, with its **images**, for browsing **offline**.

Comment: You don't have a lot of luck - an official app was added about 3 hours before you answered. ;)

Comment: yeah tough luck, but it wasn't there when I answered, and it's not showing in my market now either.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have tried the web-based version. Interestingly enough, if you add a shortcut to it it has a special icon. I've tried some of the other ones and seem to always go back to the web-based version.

Comment: Yes I currently use the web based version but would like a widget. I also prefer official apps when they are available.